# Convert a list of hexadecimal numbers to decimal

Tags: list-manipulation

I know that to change a single number from hexadecimal representation to decimal, you can use: `base^^digits`.

However, if you have a list of numbers, Mathematica seems to treat the list name as the number, rather than as an item in a list.

For example:

```
16^^56 = 86
```

But:

```
u={56, 57, 58};
16^^u[[1]] = error
```

With the error message: General::digit: "Digit at position 1 in u is too large to be used in base 16."

So it's trying to literally convert u[[1]] to hexadecimal!

I've tried using `ToExpression[u[[1]]]`, but that didn't help. How do I convert a list of numbers from hexadecimal to decimal? Thanks!

Comment: Probably a bad idea to hex a decimal anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau   that joke is way past its prime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `^^` syntax is only used for inputting literals.  You want to use `FromDigits`, e.g.

```
FromDigits[#, 16] & /@ {"56", "57", "58"}
```

Note that the input numbers must be strings.  `56` is a decimal number only.  In order to input numbers with higher or lower bases you must use a string (i.e. `"56"`).

Comment: To automate this little more, may be `FromDigits[#, 16] & /@ (ToString[#] & /@ u)`

Answer (score 8):

Using the new `Interpreter` in ver10+

```
listhex = {"56", "7f", "ff"};
Interpreter["HexInteger"]@listhex

(* Out {86, 127, 255} *)
```

and this can be coupled with `ToString` a la Nasser

The `Interpreter` function seems to have the undocumented(?) ability to act directly on "Ox.." format  e.g.

```
fromHexString[value_] := Interpreter["HexInteger"][value];
fromHexString @ {"0x4f", "f", "0x80", "0x83", "83", "f2", "c6", "d2", "60", "16"}

(*Out {79, 15, 128, 131, 131, 242, 198, 210, 96, 22} *)
```