# How to translate/convert UTF-16 code to its corresponding word/characters by Mathematica?

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding, input-forms

I'm using Mathematica10.0.2 on my Win7. Recently I crawled some websites by mathematica and within the information returned by URLFetch there are plenty of UTF-16M codes. These UTF-16M codes are actually the names of web user and I intended to translate them into normal words or characters.

a sample of UTF-16M codes looks like

```
"\u5929\u4e0a\u4eba\u95f4"
```

(*If you manipulate the string above the Mathematica might warning with a heap of "Unknown string escape \u." But this is not the key point*)

There are online tools to convert UTF-16 codes to the TEXT, here is a example:
http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html

If you type the codes such as `5929` or `4e0a` or `4eba` or `95f4` into the website above, the Output would give you the corresponding word/characters.

My problem is how could I do this **by Mathematica automatically**?

I tried

```
 ImportString["5929", "Character16"]
```

It gave wrong result.

tried

```
 FromCharacterCode[
 ToCharacterCode[
 ImportString[
 "\\u5927", {"Character16"}]], #] & /@
 $CharacterEncodings
```

still all same wrong results

```
 FromCharacterCode[
 ToCharacterCode[
 "\\u5927"], #] & /@ $CharacterEncodings
```

didn't work...

What should I do?

(*Err something like `URLFetch["http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html","Method"->"POST",...]` might be too awkward *)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want this specific char:

[Unicode Han Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5929/index.htm)

The issue is not with Mathematica's character code conversion, but instead the encoding source.

The value you have obtained is in Hex, where you need the decimal to use `FromCharacterCode`.

Hex-> Dec-> Front end

```
FromCharacterCode[Interpreter["HexInteger"]["5929"]]
```

[image: Interp]

References

[78666](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78666/convert-a-list-of-hexadecimal-numbers-to-decimal)

Comment: Great find, I tried, but the only relevant search result I found from "UTF-16M" was the converter linked to in the OP

Comment: you don't need to search "UTF-16M", just search UTF-16. @JasonB

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `FromDigits`:

```
FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16] &
  /@ StringSplit["\u5929\u4e0a\u4eba\u95f4", "\u"]]
```